# React/Meteor - call this.setState inside an Autoform hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'd like to modify the state of a React component when a Meteor autoform is submitted.
My code is below. I know it has something to do with scope, but I've fiddled around with where and how I call this.setState and nothing seems to work.
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Just needed to reassign "this".

[image]

Comment: The other way is to use the arrow function as a callback for `addHooks`.